# BigQuery update running median on second table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several tables that contain sensordata that consist of 2 colums:

timestamp | value

I want a second table that adds a new line when a new value comes into one of the above tables, that takes the last xx values, calculates the median, and adds this line.

How is this best done in BQ / Scheduled query? I know how to calculate a median, just hardest is to do the append 'on schedule'.

Comment: Consider Using a View.  You can have your source table with all of the timestamps and values, then a view that does the calculations and limitations that you want.

Answer (score 0):

For append data into a table in a scheduled query, you require to set the *Append to table* option in the **Destination table write preference** when the scheduled query is [configured](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) in the by [BigQuery UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?_ga=2.177931237.-1925678854.1566439660):

[image]